# Mocking a controller method at CakePHP

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, mocking, cakephp-2.0

I am having troubles to test one of my methods because it uses a vendor class with no model.

Well, the thing is that i want that method to return me what i want. 
I have been told that mocking a method is to make it return what i want.

For example, when i call "foo()" method i want it to return me true always.

How can i do it? At CakePHP cookbook i can find this:

```
$Posts = $this->generate('Posts', array(
    'methods' => array(
        'isAuthorized'
    ),
    'models' => array(
        'Post' => array('save')
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'RequestHandler' => array('isPut'),
        'Email' => array('send'),
        'Session'
    )
));
```

So i guess i should have to use the fist option: method
But... how to make it return what i want?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to achieve, what's going wrong and what you've already tried... Please clarify your question so we can be able to help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. Someone told me that mocking a method you can make it return what you want. I want a method from my controller to return me TRUE when i call it from the test. Is it possible mocking it?

Comment: @jeremyharris, the other question was a bit different and i didn't understand well your answer for the occasion. In this case i find it much more clear and useful. Thanks!!

Comment: @Steve No problem, just comment if you don't understand and people generally try to clarify :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the answer I gave you in this question: [How can i test an Add function on CakePHP2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173506/how-can-i-test-an-add-function-on-cakephp2-0/10176298#10176298)

```
$Posts = $this->generate('Posts', array(
    'methods' => array(
        'isAuthorized'
    ),
    'models' => array(
        'Post' => array('save')
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'RequestHandler' => array('isPut'),
        'Email' => array('send'),
        'Session'
    )
));

// tell PHPUnit that `isAuthorized` should return true any time it's called
$Posts
  ->expects($this->any())
  ->method('isAuthorized')
  ->will($this->returnValue(true));
// tell PHPUnit to expect `isPut` once, and to return false
$Posts
  ->RequestHandler
  ->expects($this->once())
  ->method('isPut')
  ->will($this->returnValue(false));
```

For more information on mocking: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html

Comment: Thanks @jeremyharris!! This was exactly was i was looking for!! A method (not a component or model) returning what i want.