# Test add() method with CakePHP 3 and PHPUnit doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I used **bake** to generate the **controller** of my **users** table, now I need to test using `PHPUnit` and `CakePHP 3` if a record has been entered in the database but I can not see if this actually being inserted.

> I can not apply this solution: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173506/how-can-i-test-an-add-function-on-cakephp2-0)

First error:

> 1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testAdd Failed
>   asserting that '' contains "The user has been saved.".

If I remove the assertion (or change to assertResponseSuccess)

```
$this->assertResponseContains('The user has been saved.');
```

in assertEquals the array `$result` is empty.

add Action in UsersController:

```
public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $userTypes = $this->Users->UserTypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('user', 'userTypes'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

testAdd in UsersControllerTest:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $this->get('/users/add');
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $data = [
        'id' => 999999,
        'email' => 'usuariocomum999999@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'usuariocomum999999senha',
        'username' => 'usuariocomum999999username',
        'user_type_id' => 900000,
        'created' => '2014-07-17 18:46:47',
        'modified' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'
    ];

    $this->post('/users/add', $data);
    $this->assertResponseContains('The user has been saved.');

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $expected = [
        [
            'id' => 999999,
            'email' => 'usuariocomum999999@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'usuariocomum999999senha',
            'username' => 'usuariocomum999999username',
            'user_type_id' => 900000,
            'created' => new Time('2014-07-17 18:46:47'),
            'modified' => new Time('2015-07-17 18:46:47')
        ]
    ];

    $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $query = $users->find('all', [
        'fields' => ['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.password',
            'Users.username', 'Users.user_type_id', 'Users.created',
            'Users.modified'],
        'conditions' => ['Users.id' => 999999]
    ]);
    $result = $query->hydrate(false)->toArray();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

Datasource test:

```
  'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'shop',
        'password' => 'shop',
        'database' => 'shoppingtest',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ]
```

**Note:** CakePHP 3.0.11 and PHPUnit 4.8.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test that there was a redirect and a success message in the `Session`, The response will not contain your text as the response is just a redirect header code for the browser.

Comment: You can make an example?